# Disable clicks on div class but need enable clicks of same nested class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have one div class named expandInnerDivStyle I need to disable clicks inside this div for this I'm doing like this

```
$(".expandInnerDivStyle").css({pointerEvents: "none"});
```

but In the div there may nested div with same class,Now I need to enable clicks for this nested div of same class.

My requirement.
I have Collapsible header div class named expandInnerDivStyle. on click of this Before disabling all the form elements inside but before diabling need to check again if there is nested header contains of same expandInnerDivStyle.

On click this need to verify if nested header id this if there then it should be enable(so i can click on this to see form elemets) but the form elements of nested header should disable.

Example of my scenario.

```
<div class="expandInnerDivStyle"> Disable this.
   <div class="parent abc"></div>  Disable this.
   <div clas="expandInnerDivStyle"> Need to enable clicks(Nested Class)
      <div class="child mno"></div> Disable this.
      <div class="child mpqr"> Disable this.
           <div clas="expandInnerDivStyle">Need to enable clicks(Nested Class)
                <button/> Disable this.
           </div>
      </div> 
   </div>
   <div class="parent hhh"></div> Disable this.
</div>
```

Please can any help me on this. Thanks.

Comment: you need to set `pointerEvents: "all"` to those child elements

Comment: I'm new to jquery can you help me for the code snippet. @Maximus

Comment: did [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40438253/2545680) help?

Comment: No it making even the Header click also disable

Comment: so did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$(".expandInnerDivStyle").css({pointerEvents: "none"});
$(".expandInnerDivStyle .expandInnerDivStyle").css({pointerEvents: "all"});
```

However, with this approach you'll still have event listener triggered on top level `expandInnerDivStyle` if you have it there when clicked on child element with pointer events all